# How to determine tuple types?

Tags: c#, .net, tuples

Apparently `ITuple` is internal, disabling a solution such as `typeof(ITuple).IsAssignableFrom(type)`. By alternative, what is the most effective way to determine `Tuple<>` till `Tuple<,,,,,,,>`? A solution without type name comparison is preferable.

Comment: What do you mean "determine"? Do you have an example of some objects and what you're trying to learn from them?

Comment: While you can't directly use `typeof(ITuple)` you can still use `Type.GetType("System.ITuple, mscorlib")` to get it.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I believe what he is asking is, "I have an object. I don't know for sure that it is a Tuple, and I don't know how how many type parameters were used, or what they are, even if it is a tuple. How can I check?"

Comment: Thanks @vcsjones. That is a much clearer problem statement.

Comment: @vcsjones - Tuple objects are not involved, only Type objects for any tuple type from `Tuple<>` till `Tuple<,,,,,,,>`.

Comment: @Dirk - Thanks, are there any security drawbacks for such reflection?

Comment: @toplel32 No, but relying on some internal features could break the program if future .NET versions change it.

Comment: Why do you need to determine if a type is a tuple?

Comment: @CodesInChaos - For a type contracting system in conjunction with a serializer of a certain human-readable format.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this:

```
public static bool IsTupleType(Type type, bool checkBaseTypes = false)
{
    if (type == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(type));

    if (type == typeof(Tuple))
        return true;

    while (type != null)
    {
        if (type.IsGenericType)
        {
            var genType = type.GetGenericTypeDefinition();
            if (genType == typeof(Tuple<>)
                || genType == typeof(Tuple<,>)
                || genType == typeof(Tuple<,,>)
                || genType == typeof(Tuple<,,,>)
                || genType == typeof(Tuple<,,,,>)
                || genType == typeof(Tuple<,,,,,>)
                || genType == typeof(Tuple<,,,,,,>)
                || genType == typeof(Tuple<,,,,,,,>)
                || genType == typeof(Tuple<,,,,,,,>))
                return true;
        }

        if (!checkBaseTypes)
            break;

        type = type.BaseType;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: This seems like the only reliable solution.

Comment: Second please, I want make this method more reliable.

Comment: You may want to rename to `IsTypeOfTuple` because `IsTuple` suggests handling an instance.

Comment: Note that `Tuple` is static.

Comment: I know, but it is Tuple after all. You can call this like IsTypeOfTuple(typeof(Tuple))

Comment: I was thinking in terms of my project, where such entitlement for `System.Tuple` is unnatural, therefore the notice.

Comment: I agree that the test for `typeof(Tuple)` is likely not what people want in most cases.

Comment: You might also need to check `type.IsConstructedGenericType` if you don't want `IsTypeOfTuple(typeof(Tuple<,,,>))` to return `true`.

Comment: The `TypeInfo` class is way too outdated. It should provide better support for modern types like `Action<nT>`, get collection type and many more features.

Comment: @rtf_leg The instance provided here is expected to be `Type`, so `IsTuple` should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I know the OP prefers no type name comparison, but for the reference, I'm including this short solution that determines whether a type is a value-tuple:

```
var x = (1, 2, 3);

var xType = x.GetType();   
var tType = typeof(ValueTuple);   

var isTuple = xType.FullName.StartsWith(tType.FullName)
```

You can add `xType.Assembly == tType.Assembly` to be certain.